# falha ao tentar atribuir propriedade de um objeto com índice de um array

Tags: php

Estou tentando atribuir o indice de um array a um objeto mas estou recebendo o seguinte erro; Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

```
// filtro estado
             $anuncios = array();
             $anunciosFiltro = $dalAnuncio->pesquisar();
             $dalLocalizacaoAUX = new dalLocalizacao();
             foreach ($anunciosFiltro as $anunciosArray) 
             {
                 $localizacaoPesquisa = new localizacao();
                 $localizacaoPesquisa->setCd($anunciosArray["cd_localizacao"]);  // o erro é reproduzido aqui
                 $localizaEstado = $dalLocalizacaoAUX->pesquisarPorId($localizacaoPesquisa)->getEstado(); 
                 $localizaMunicpio = $dalLocalizacaoAUX->pesquisarPorId($localizacaoPesquisa)->getMunicipio();
                 if($estado == $localizaEstado)
                 {
                     $anunciosQtdTotal++;
                         if(count($anuncios) < $max)
                         {
                         $anuncios[] = $anunciosArray;
                         }
                 }
             }
             $result['totalAnuncios'] = $anunciosQtdTotal;
            $anuncios = $dalAnuncio->filtrarPorEstado($estado, $init, $max);
            $result['totalAnuncios'] = count($anuncios);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso está acontecendo porque você está tentando acessar a chave de um objeto como se o objeto fosse um array. Não dá para dizer pelo seu código, mas seria `$anunciosFiltro` gerado por um JSON? JSON_DECODE gera objetos ao invés de arrays.

De qualquer forma, para acessar chaves de um objeto, utilize `->`

```
$anunciosArray['cd_localizacao'];  /*forma de acessar a chave de um array*/
$anunciosArray->cd_localizacao;    /*forma de acessar a chave de um objeto*/

$chave = 'cd_localizacao';
$anunciosArray[$chave];    /*forma de acessar a chave de um array dinamicamente*/
$anunciosArray->{$chave};  /*forma de acessar a chave de um objeto dinamicamente*/
```